# Deploying InfoPath 2010 browser enabled forms as Sandbox solutions using WSP

Tags: infopath, sandbox-solution

Is there a way through which I can deploy a InfoPath browser enabled form with code behind as a Sandbox solution via WSP?

I tried something around the approach we used to follow for deploying InfoPath Administrator Approved form templates back in MOSS but could not succeed.

Any help/pointers appreciated.